# how can I implement the graph api in a language that is not supported?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement the graph api in "tcl", there's no SDK for it in the facebook developers site (no even in third party sdks), how do I go on about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a SDK. The Facebook Graph API is a REST Webservice. The only thing to do is, use the webservice in your tcl code.

How to use webservices in tcl see: http://core.tcl.tk/tclws/wiki?name=WSClient+Client+Side